# Access form not working after migrating backend from Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, variant

I have an Access form where you can insert a new record into the system. The form has the following fields:

```
Date File Created*: [text box]
First Name*: [text box]
Surname*:[text box]
DOB*:[text box]
TeamCode*:[text box]
AutoNumber:[text box]
cID*: [text box]
```

Now before migration, this form used to work as follow:
As soon as user entered the Firstname, an Autonumber was generated automatically and this number was assigned to the cID(PK), so that, the cID(pk) is same as autonumber. Everthing was working perfectly fine but after migrating the backend to SQL Server, as soon as user start to even click on the first name text box they get an error and no autonumber is generated:

```
Runtime Error '-2147352567 (80020009)'
You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type.
```

I have tried everything but I'm unable to fix this error. Please find the error picture through the attached link.

Code:

```
Public Function UpdatecID()
    If IsNull(Me.FormcID) Or Me.FormcID = 0 Then
=>        Me.FormcID = Me.Form_AutoN
    End If
End Function
```

[image: Error message]

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Hit "Debug" and add the relevant parts of the VBA code to your question.

Comment: @Andre Thank you for your reply. I have added the part of code where the error is. I have also highlighted the part with an arrow in the code  '=>' where the error is occurring. Thanks once again.

Comment: Why do you have two fields with same data? Why is the autonumber field not the primary key? What does code show as value of Form_AutoN when error occurs?

Comment: @June7 Thank you for your reply. This form was designed way back to create a cID separately from AutoNum. We did not want to use Autonum as FK in other tables. The value of Forn_AutoN is shown as NULL when in debug mode. This issue occurred when migrated the backend to SQL Server. It is working properly with the access backend.

Comment: This is a known hurdle when switching from Access backend to Sql Server. Access creates the autonumber immediately when creating the new record, Sql Server not until the new record is saved. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662892/how-to-get-the-autonumber-generated-by-an-sql-insert

Comment: Are you calling `UpdatecID` in the `Form_BeforeInsert` event?

Comment: @dbmitch  Thank you for your reply. No, I'm not calling ```UpdatecID```  in ```Form_BeforeInsert``` event.

Comment: @Andre Thank you so much for your reply. I will go through the link you mentioned. Thanks once again.

Comment: @dbmitch Thank you so much.  I was able to make it fully work after going through the link you attached here.   Also, I would like to thank everyone for taking the time to help me. :)